error: this attempt to set a cookie via SET-Cookie header was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host url
I'm implementing authentication in a Node.js application by setting JWT tokens in cookies. Although the API request returns a status code of 200, the cookies are not being stored in the browser. Additionally, an error message states, "This attempt to set a cookie via the Set-Cookie header was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host URL." Furthermore, there is also a 307 Temporary Redirect error shown in the screenshots.


here is api code for authentication
try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!email || !password) {
      res.status(400);
      throw new Error("All fields are required");
    }

    const admin = await SuperAdmin.find({ email });
    if (admin.length === 0) {
      res.status(400);
      throw new Error("Invalid email or password");
    }

    if (admin && (await bcrypt.compare(password, admin[0].password))) {
      const accessToken = jwt.sign(
        {
          admin: {
            _id: admin[0]._id,
          },
        },
        process.env.JWT_KEY,
        { expiresIn: "1d" }
      );
      res.cookie("token", accessToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        domain: "localhost",
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "Lax",
        maxAge: 3 * 24 * 60 * 100,
      });

      res.status(200).json({ message: "login successful" });
    } else {
      res.status(400);
      throw new Error("email or password is not valid");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }


domain: "localhost", is wrong unless the request happens to be coming from a localhost:// URL.

Leave out the domain: property in the cookie, and it will set the cookie for the current domain by default. This property is only needed when setting the cookie for a container domain from a subdomain.

i m not getting this error, but still getting 307 Temporary Redirect. Stuck at OPTION call
